# Meteor routing with iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried implementing iron:Router in the Meteor official TODO app tutorial. I wanted to make the default "/" route point to the "home" template so I modified my todoapp.html page and encapsulated the whole code in a template tag like this:

```
    <template name = "home">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <ul>
          {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </body>
    </template>
    <template name = "task">
<li>
 <span class="text"><a href="/user">{{username}}</a> - {{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

and in the todoapp.js I added this before isClient and isServer:

```
Router.route('/', {
    template: 'home'
});
```

Before adding the home template I got all the "task" objects. After encapsulating the code in a "home" template I don't get any of them. I followed the official [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates) to implement the "todo" app.

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`head` and `body` don't below in templates. Try this instead:

```
<head></head>
<body>
</body>

<template name="home">
  Home
  <ul>
    {{#each tasks}}
      {{> task}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="task">
  Task
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. :( It yields but the styling is all gone, and the tasks are not visible.

Comment: is my routing correct? `Router.route('/', {
    template: 'home'
});`

Comment: well your task template is empty (at least in your question). Also, there is no difference in style definition in my version vs. yours.

Comment: I've added some "canary" text to the templates, so you can make sure that the templates themselves render, even if your tasks don't. Can you check that and see whether it shows up?

Comment: As mentioned in the tutorials, I created the tasks in the .js file as MongoDB collection objects. So it should not be the task definition that's a problem. And, I have also updated the task template in the question. could you please take a look at that and help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89089/discussion-between-christian-fritz-and-tania).